# Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@g.com,
>   'User'.'phone' = 87665r5, 'User'.'address' = 23lsdhf,
>   'User'.'location' ' at line 1

SQL Query: 
`UPDATE 'cake'.'users' AS 'User' SET 'User'.'username' = paul, 'User'.'password' = eben, 'User'.'email' = paul@g.com, 'User'.'phone' = 87665r5, 'User'.'address' = 23lsdhf, 'User'.'location' = lskjaflasi, 'User'.'pincode' = 867567 WHERE 'User'.'id' = 1`

My code is

```
       if($this->request->data)
        {$User=$this->request->data[User];
    $this->User->updateAll($User,array("User.id" => $v));}
```

How can I update the whole form?

Comment: You haven't wrapped your string values in single quotes.

Comment: @HoboSapiens is there any easy way to wrap them in single quotes Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateAll()` does not automatically wrap string values in quotes unlike when using `save()`. You have to do this yourself. From [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions):-

> Literal values should be quoted manually using DboSource::value().

You need to wrap each string value in `$this->request->data` with quotes using something like the datasource's `value()` method before calling `updateAll()`:-

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$value = $db->value($value, 'string');
```

It is advisable to not just pass `$this->request->data` to `updateAll()` anyway as someone could inject data into your database. Instead build a new array of save data from your request data and wrap strings as appropriate. For example:-

```
$user=$this->request->data[User]
$data = array(
    'username' => $db->value($user['username'], 'string'),
    'password' => $db->value($user['password'], 'string'),
    'email' => $db->value($user['email'], 'string'),
    'phone' => $db->value($user['phone'], 'string'),
    'address' => $db->value($user['address'], 'string'),
    'location' => $db->value($user['location'], 'string'),
    'pincode' => $db->value($user['pincode'], 'integer')
);
$this->User->updateAll($data, array("User.id" => $v));
```

**Update**

As an alternative to using `updateAll()` you would be better to use `save()` for what you are doing here. As long as your save data contains the record's primary key (*e.g.* `User.id`) it will perform an `UPDATE` rather than an `INSERT`:-

```
$this->request->data['User']['id'] = $v;
$this->User->save($this->request->data);
```

`save()` will handle all the strings for you so there is no need for wrapping them in quotes yourself.

Comment: Thanks @drmonkeyninja is there any other possibilities that you could suggest me ? Thanks.!

Comment: @Paul I've updated the answer to show a better way using `save()` as `updateAll()` is a bit redundant in your specific example. If you do need to use `updateAll()` and need to easily wrap all the string values with quotes you could use the PHP function `array_map` to quickly wrap each value in quotation marks.