# CAKEPHP 2.0 updateALL, json_encoded data

Tags: php, mysql, json, cakephp, update-all

I have another problem with one of my controller functions. I have written a function that updates some fields from my database. I am grabbing the content from a decoded json_file and after I grabbed the data I have encoding it again so I could store it in my database. I am getting some errors I do not understand.

**My function**

```
public function admin_update_rulings()
{
    $this->loadModel('Magicsets');
    $this->loadModel('Cards');
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $code = 'LEA';
    $cards = file_get_contents('http://mtgjson.com/json/' . $code . '-x.json');

    $decodedcards = json_decode($cards);
    $this->Card->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


    foreach ($decodedcards->cards as $cards) {
        $mvid = $cards->multiverseid;
        $legal = json_encode($cards->legalities);
        $rulings = '';
        if (!empty($cards->rulings)) {
            $rulings = json_encode($cards->rulings);
        } else {
            $rulings = json_encode('leeg');
        }

        $this->Cards->updateAll(
            array('rulings' => $rulings),   //fields to update
            array('multiverseid' => $mvid)  //condition
        );
    }
}
```

The error message I get:

Database Error

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an             error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server   version for the right syntax to use near '[{"date":"2008-08-01","text":"This card has been returned to its original functi' at line 1
>
> SQL Query: UPDATE `magicmm`.`cards` AS `Cards` SET `Cards`.`rulings` = [{"date":"2008-08-01","text":"This card has been returned to its original functionality. If it is enchanting an artifact that's already a creature, it won't change its power and toughness."},{"date":"2008-08-01","text":"A noncreature permanent that turns into a creature can attack, and its {T} abilities can be activated, only if its controller has continuously controlled that permanent since the beginning of his or her most recent turn. It doesn't matter how long the permanent has been a creature."}] WHERE `multiverseid` = 96

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create   app/View/Errors/pdo_error.ctp

Any help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated :-).

Comment: Consider the following if you're storing json with Cakephp: http://bakery.cakephp.org/2012/10/09/JSON-with-your-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap strings in quotation marks when using `updateAll()` in Cake. You can do this using the datasource's `value()` method:-

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$value = $db->value($rulings, 'string');
$this->Cards->updateAll(
    array('rulings' => $rulings),   //fields to update
    array('multiverseid' => $mvid)  //condition
);
```

You're probably better off using `save()` rather than `updateAll()` if you know the primary key when saving.

See the accepted answer to [Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098426/error-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064-you-have-an-error) for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice everyone. I decided to look into the save method that both of you adviced me to use. It resolved the issue for me and everything is working now. I changed my update code to this.

```
        $updaterow = $this->Cards->find('first', array('fields' => array('id'), 'conditions' => array('multiverseid' => $mvid), 'limit' => 1));
        $id = $updaterow['Cards']['id'];

        $data = array('id' => $id, 'rulings' => $rulings, 'legalities' => $legal);

        $this->Cards->save($data);
```