# How to update password field through CakePHP form

Tags: cakephp, hash, md5

I am using below code. but it's not updating as hash value. Just saving as input value. Please help.

```
$this->request->data['User']['password'] = md5($this->request->data['User']['password']);
if ($this->User->updateAll(array('User.password' => $this->request->data['User']['password']),array('User.id' => $newsid))) {
$this->Session->setFlash("Password Changed");
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'));  
          } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash("password not changed");
            $this->render();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, In cake php md5 is not necessary for password field, What version do u use in cakephp?

Comment: But by this code. How can I save password as hash value?

Comment: What error do you got ? ,You need to updated one row or all row ?

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c920c1595dcdb710a8cbd045b9735acb' in 'field list'                                         UPDATE `demo`.`users` AS `User` SET `User`.`password` = c920c1595dcdb710a8cbd045b9735acb WHERE `User`.`id` = 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if ($this->User->updateAll(array('User.password' => "'".$this->request->data['User']['password']."'"),array('User.id' => $newsid))) {   
                $this->Session->setFlash("Password Changed");
              $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'));  

            }
```

A string value should be wrapped by inverted comma.

Comment: Yes you solved my problem. There was simple single cotation missing.

Comment: Please, when giving such advises, don't forget to mention that it's **absolutely crucial** to pass **only 100% safe data** that way, as the value is not being escaped, and thus not safe against SQL injections. Noobs will copy and paste this without knowing the possible implications. It's always better to advise [**to use the database drivers `value()` method**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098426/error-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064-you-have-an-error/31098729#31098729) as described in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Before Save in Model:

```
 public function beforeSave($option = array()) {
 if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
 $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
  }
return true;
}
```

Controller File:

```
public function Change_password($id = null) {

$this->User->id = $id;
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
$this->User->saveField('password', $this->request->data['User']['password']);
}
```

If using before save function ,if password fields is not empty its automatically save in hash format.